# Can I find out how many questions I have asked across all Stack Exchange networks?

Tags: discussion, statistics

Is there a nice and easy way to find the above out without having to go through each one manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone could make an app for this using the API, go to stackapps.com and ask there.